# How to get the memory consumed by SQL variables, columns etc.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory

I know basic SQL/RDBMS and not the kind of detailed information a highly experienced DBA would know.

I need to know how much memory is consumed by a variable such as int, bigint, date time. I also need to know how much memory is consumed by a Varchar(50) column in two cases -

```
1] The Column is filled with strings of size 50
2] Column has all Null
```

The purpose behind this is to make estimates for ETL/data transfer.

I also want to know how to store SQL server result into a cache on disk and then retrieve the data from that cache, chunk by chunk (doing this due to memory related concerns). But, I'll make that another question.

Comment: Did you check [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) documentation for data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [documentation linked in the comment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), note that `varchar` storage depends on what data is actually entered.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089(v=sql.100).aspx:

> The storage size is the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes.

Comment: How do you convert length of data into bytes ? Eg. If I have varchar(50) containing 10digit codes only, then what is the memory consumed by one such row ? Once i get that, I can add the 2Bytes and get full memory.

Comment: If you have a varchar(50) containing the value '1234567890' then I believe that will consume 10+2 = 12 bytes.  If it was a char(50) then it would consume 50 bytes regardless of contents.